# CodeFile OK, CodeBehind gives "not declared" error

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I have an asp project that works fine with CodeFile, but when I change it to CodeBehind, the vb functions are not recognized in the aspx file, giving a "Name ... is not declared" error in the aspx file.

In order to use CodeBehind, is there something else that should be done besides changing `codefile` to `codebehind` in the top line?

The following code gets the error "Name 'connex' is not declared," in the aspx file.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="browse.aspx.vb" Inherits="_browse" %> <!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head runat="server"> <title>Test</title> </head> 
<body> 
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<%
  Dim s As String = connex()  
  Response.Write(s)
%>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

==================

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web

Partial Public Class _browse
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Function connex() As String
  Return "OK"
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I believe `Inherits="MyNameSpace._browse"` is required when your application has a root namespace, which you can find in project properties. I believe the root namespace defaults to your application's original name. Without a root namespace, `Inherits="_browse"` would probably work. When working with DNN, I remove root namespaces, but I leave it in for all other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your

```
Inherits="_browse"
```

Make sure to include the correct namespace.

```
Inherits="MyNameSpace._browse"
```

Comment: Thanks! That does it. I have to remove the namespace for codefile, add it for codebehind.